# Comparing Date objects using localeCompare

Tags: javascript

I need to compare between 2 Date objects (to sort an array according to the result).
By difference, I mean to the level of seconds.
Does some one know if it can be done by using `localeCompare()`?
If not, what's the best way?
Is it enough to do:

```
let d1 = new Date();
let d2 = new Date();
return d1 - d2;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following a standard function to calculate the difference between 2 days and returning the number of days difference. You could try it if it works for you.

```js
/**
// Calculate the difference in days
// between 2 dates
// Returns positive if date1 < date2, otherwise negative.
//
//  @param   {Date}  date1  - Start date
**  @param   {Date}  date2  - End date
**  @returns {number} - whole number of days between date2 and date2
**
*/

function dateDiffDays(date1, date2) {
  return Math.round((new Date(new Date(date2)).setHours(12)-new Date(new Date(date1)).setHours(12))/8.64e7);
}

// ================= test ============

console.log(dateDiffDays("2000-02-28","2001-02-28"))                   // 366 Leap year
console.log(dateDiffDays("2000 02 28","2001-02-28"))                   // 366 Leap year
console.log(dateDiffDays("2001-02-28","2002-02-28"))                   // 365 Non Leap
console.log(dateDiffDays("2015-12-28 00:00:01","2015-12-28 23:59:59")) // 0 days
console.log(dateDiffDays("2015-12-28 23:59:59","2015-12-29 00:00:01")) // 1 day
console.log(dateDiffDays("2015-12-28","2015-12-29"))                   // 1 day
console.log(dateDiffDays(new Date(2020,0,10),new Date(2020,0,1) ))     // -9
console.log(dateDiffDays("20xx 01 30","2001 01 30"))                   // NaN
console.log(dateDiffDays("","2001 01 30"))                             // Nan
console.log(dateDiffDays())                                            // Nan
```